# Joins and removing Cartesian Products

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

I have 5 regions that each contain 1 store and 1 warehouse.  I have a table that contains the regions and corresponding stores and warehouses.  I also have a table that lists the inventories of both the stores and warehouses.  Finally, have a table that lists the allowed quantities for the warehouse.   If I look at the inventory table right now it would say something like:

```
FACILITY ID        ITEM_NUMBER    QTY
  STORE 1              15D         2 
 WAREHOUSE 1           15D         1
```

The problem is, Store 1 and Warehouse 1 belong to region 1 and I would like to see it in this format:

```
REGION    WAREHOUSE    QTY OH     STORE    QTY OH 
  1           1          2          1         1
```

and so on...   So I wrote the following SQL:

```
Create or replace view REGION_BALANCES
as
with WAREHOUSES as 
(select A.REGION_CODE, A.REG_DESC, A.WAREHOUSE_NUMBER, A.FACILITY_ID,
        C.ITEM_NUMBER, sum(C.IN_STOCK_QTY) as IN_STOCK_QTY,
        B.ALLOWED_QTY
 from   REG_WHS_STR_ASSOC A                                    join
        ALLOWANCES        B on (A.FACILITY_ID = B.FACILITY_ID) join
        INVENTORIES       C on (A.FACILITY_ID = FACILITY_ID) and (B.ITEM_NUMBER = C.ITEM_NUMBER)
 group  by A.REGION_CODE, A.REG_DESC, A.WAREHOUSE_NUMBER, C.ITEM_NUMBER, B.ALLOWED_QTY), 
STORES as 
(select A.REGION_CODE, A.REG_DESC, A.STORE_NUMBER, A.FACILITY_ID, B.ITEM_NUMBER,
        sum(B.IN_STOCK_QTY) as IN_STOCK_QTY
 from   REG_WHS_STR_ASSOC A                                    join
        INVENTORIES       B on (A.FACILITY_ID = B.FACILITY_ID)
 group  by A.REGION_CODE, A.REG_DESC, A.STORE_NUMBER, B.ITEM_NUMBER
)
select A.REGION_CODE, A.REG_DESC, A.WAREHOUSE_NUMBER, A.FACILITY_ID,
       WAREHOUSES.ITEM_NUMBER, WAREHOUSES.IN_STOCK_QTY, WAREHOUSES.ALLOWED_QTY,
       STORES.STORE_NUMBER, STORES.FACILITY_ID, STORES.ITEM_NUMBER, STORES.IN_STOCK_QTY
from   REG_WHS_STR_ASSOC A                                             join
       WAREHOUSES          on (A.REGION_CODE = WAREHOUSES.REGION_CODE) join
       STORES              on (A.REGION_CODE = STORES.REGION_CODE)
order by 5,1 asc;
```

I have changed my join around from left joins to right joins to cross joins to inner joins; however, I either get 30 records (and I need hundreds of records)  or I get Cartesian products.  Can anyone provide advice to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: After reformatting your query to make it readable I see that the syntax on line 9 is broken: `join INVENTORIES C on (A.FACILITY_ID = FACILITY_ID) and B.ITEM_NUMBER = C.ITEM_NUMBER)`.  Is the `and` supposed to be part of the `join on` clause?  There's an extra right paren at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that.  Yes it is supposed to have the beginning parenthesis.  I made the mistake here and not on TOAD.  I will fix that though.  Thank you for pointing it out.  The statement runs on Toad; however, it either gives me a ridiculously small amount of records or a Cartesian Product.

Comment: Can you set up a sqlfiddle?

Comment: @terary  I've never done that before, but it's very interesting.  I set one up [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee7c43)

Comment: This is apparently a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851224/create-view-having-trouble-with-joins

Answer (score 0):

Where is this going?  Are you using some programming to pull this data.

```
SELECT
REGION_CODE, REG_DESC, WAREHOUSE_NUMBER, WAREHOUSE_FACILITY_ID, STORE_NUMBER, STORE_FACILITY_ID,
FACILITY_ID, ITEM_NUMBER, IN_STOCK_QTY

FROM REG_WHS_STR_ASSOC R 
INNER JOIN Inventories I ON I.FACILITY_ID = R.WAREHOUSE_FACILITY_ID OR I.FACILITY_ID = R.STORE_FACILITY_ID
GROUP BY REGION_CODE, REG_DESC, WAREHOUSE_NUMBER, WAREHOUSE_FACILITY_ID, STORE_NUMBER, STORE_FACILITY_ID,
FACILITY_ID, ITEM_NUMBER, IN_STOCK_QTY
```

I think that is kind of what you are looking for. To squish it more I think you would have to use subqueries - that is fine but maybe not so efficient.   But I think this will get you what you are looking for mostly - you will have to dink with it a bit more for your purposes