# Create View having trouble with JOINS

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 5 regions that each contain 1 store and 1 warehouse.  I have a table that contains the regions and corresponding stores and warehouses.  I also have a table that lists the inventories of both the stores and warehouses.  Finally, have a table that lists the allowed quantities for the warehouse.   If I look at the inventory table right now it would say something like:

```
FACILITY ID        ITEM_NUMBER    QTY
  STORE 1              15D         2 
 WAREHOUSE 1           15D         1
```

The problem is, Store 1 and Warehouse 1 belong to region 1 and I would like to see it in this format:

```
REGION    WAREHOUSE    QTY OH     STORE    QTY OH 
  1           1          2          1         1
```

and so on...   So I wrote the following SQL:

```
Create or replace view REGION_BALANCES
as
with WAREHOUSES as 
(
select

A.REGION_CODE,A.REG_DESC,A.WAREHOUSE_NUMBER,A.FACILITY_ID,C.ITEM_NUMBER,sum(C.IN_STOCK_QTY) as IN_STOCK_QTY,  B.ALLOWED_QTY
from REG_WHS_STR_ASSOC A
join ALLOWANCES B on (A.FACILITY_ID = B.FACILITY_ID)
join INVENTORIES C on (A.FACILITY_ID = FACILITY_ID) and B.ITEM_NUMBER = C.ITEM_NUMBER)
group by A.REGION_CODE,A.REG_DESC,A.WAREHOUSE_NUMBER,C.ITEM_NUMBER,B.ALLOWED_QTY
), 
STORES as 
(
select

 A.REGION_CODE,A.REG_DESC,A.STORE_NUMBER,A.FACILITY_ID,B.ITEM_NUMBER,sum(B.IN_STOCK_QTY) as IN_STOCK_QTY
from REG_WHS_STR_ASSOC A
join INVENTORIES B on (A.FACILITY_ID = B.FACILITY_ID)
group by A.REGION_CODE,A.REG_DESC,A.STORE_NUMBER, B.ITEM_NUMBER
)
select A.REGION_CODE,A.REG_DESC,A.WAREHOUSE_NUMBER,A.FACILITY_ID,WAREHOUSES.ITEM_NUMBER,WAREHOUSES.IN_STOCK_QTY,WAREHOUSES.ALLOWED_QTY,STORES.STORE_NUMBER,STORES.FACILITY_ID,STORES.ITEM_NUMBER,STORES.IN_STOCK_QTY
from REG_WHS_STR_ASSOC A
join WAREHOUSES on (A.REGION_CODE = WAREHOUSES.REGION_CODE)
join STORES on (A.REGION_CODE = STORES.REGION_CODE)
order by 5,1 asc;
```

I have changed my join around from left joins to right joins to cross joins to inner joins; however, I either get 30 records (and I need hundreds of records)  or I get Cartesian products.  Can anyone provide advice to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is apparently duplicated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851132/joins-and-removing-cartesian-products

Answer (score 1):

You were forgetting to link warehouses and stores by item number (plus left join is the better for this case)

```
Create or replace view REGION_BALANCES
as
with WAREHOUSES as 
(
select
A.REGION_CODE, A.REG_DESC, A.WAREHOUSE_NUMBER, 
A.FACILITY_ID, C.ITEM_NUMBER,sum(C.IN_STOCK_QTY) as IN_STOCK_QTY,  B.ALLOWED_QTY
from REG_WHS_STR_ASSOC A
join ALLOWANCES B on (A.FACILITY_ID = B.FACILITY_ID)
join INVENTORIES C on (A.FACILITY_ID = FACILITY_ID) and B.ITEM_NUMBER = C.ITEM_NUMBER)
group by A.REGION_CODE,A.REG_DESC,A.WAREHOUSE_NUMBER,C.ITEM_NUMBER,B.ALLOWED_QTY
), 
STORES as 
(
select

A.REGION_CODE,A.REG_DESC,A.STORE_NUMBER, 
A.FACILITY_ID,B.ITEM_NUMBER,sum(B.IN_STOCK_QTY) as IN_STOCK_QTY
from REG_WHS_STR_ASSOC A
join INVENTORIES B on (A.FACILITY_ID = B.FACILITY_ID)
group by A.REGION_CODE,A.REG_DESC,A.STORE_NUMBER, B.ITEM_NUMBER
)
select A.REGION_CODE, A.REG_DESC,A. WAREHOUSE_NUMBER, A.FACILITY_ID, 
WAREHOUSES.ITEM_NUMBER, WAREHOUSES.IN_STOCK_QTY, WAREHOUSES.ALLOWED_QTY,
STORES.STORE_NUMBER, STORES.FACILITY_ID, STORES.ITEM_NUMBER, STORES.IN_STOCK_QTY
from REG_WHS_STR_ASSOC A
left join WAREHOUSES on (A.REGION_CODE = WAREHOUSES.REGION_CODE)
left join STORES on 
 (A.REGION_CODE = STORES.REGION_CODE AND STORES.ITEM_NUMBER = WAREHOUSES.ITEM_NUMBER)
order by 5,1 asc;
```